# I am having trouble with gcloud commands

Tags: gcloud

[image: Google Cloud]

See the screenshot attached, I keep getting that error even though, I have updated gcloud to the current version.

`Google Cloud SDK Version:` **347.0.0**

Comment: One cause for this error is a proxy causing SSL certificate validation to fail. Use the command-line tool `curl` or `openssl` to view the certificate returned for `dl.google.com`. Note: Edit your question and remove the picture. Replace with text.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I did and this is what shows up on `curl`

`curl dl.google.com`

```
<a href = "http://www.google.com/chrome">Found</a>
```

Comment: You are viewing the HTML for an HTTP 302 Found, which requires a redirect. You must specify the https protocol to fetch the certificate and follow redirects. Read the documentation on curl to process the connection. For example, adding the command line option `-v` will show you details on the connection, information on the certificate, etc. `openssl` can download the certificate for review.

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding, make sure that you have the domain names for your [Google-managed SSL certificate](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs)

Also ensure to have an SSL certificate created properly or try to [create](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl) it again.

SSL certificate must be associated with a load balancer, specifically the load balancer's target proxy.

Verify SSL certificate for load balancer.

Main step here is to “Update the DNS A and AAAA records to point to the load balancer's IP address”

Finally, you can test your SSL certificate using OpenSSL command (here you have to add the domain name and IP address of your load balancer)

Comment: it doesn't work, even if I try running `gcloud components update`. This issue has never occurred before.